# Fail to call Update action method on Kendo Grid in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have two grids where second grid displays detail data based on row selected on first grid. The second grid allows inline editing and also has upload control in one of the column where it allows to upload more than one files. I have added some custom code ([based on Damien article](http://blogs.visoftinc.com/2013/02/25/kendo-ui-upload-control-with-existing-files/)) in order to display pre-uploaded files in the upload widget during the edit mode. The issue is if the row has pre uploaded file(s) and if the row is modified (e.g. removed previously uploaded file or uploaded new file), and 'Update' command button is clicked, the update action method doesn't get fired. However, if the row doesn't have pre-uploaded file(s) and if any edit is made e.g. uploaded new file and 'Update' command button is clicked, the update action method gets fired.
 Can anyone tell me why the update action method is not getting fired and i am getting 500 error on my code?

[Here is the project code to download](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ak0-8y_PtzyUpD89LZwoKZvlo57O)

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Here is my code:

**CertificationViewModel.cs:**

```
public class Certification
{
    public string SupplierNumber      { get; set; }
    public string CustomerItemNumber  { get; set; }
}

public class CertificationDetail
{
    public string CertificationName                { get; set; }
    public bool Value                              { get; set; }
    public List<UploadInitialFile> Attachments     { get; set; }

    public CertificationDetail()
    {
        Attachments = new List<UploadInitialFile>();
    }
}

public class UploadInitialFile
{
    public UploadInitialFile(string fileName, int contentLength, string fileExtension)
    {
        Name = fileName;
        Size = contentLength;
        Extension = fileExtension;
    }

    public string Name      { get; set; }
    public int Size         { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }
    public JsonResult GetTestData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var certificationList = new List<Certification>();
        certificationList.Add(new Certification {SupplierNumber = "4343", CustomerItemNumber = "123344"});
        certificationList.Add(new Certification {SupplierNumber = "4242", CustomerItemNumber = "23453"});
        return Json(certificationList.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult GetDetailTestData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Certification model)
    {
        var certificationDetailLists = new List<CertificationDetail>();

        if (model.SupplierNumber == "4343")
        {
            certificationDetailLists.Add(new CertificationDetail {CertificationName = "ROHS", Value = true, Attachments = GetAttachments()});
            certificationDetailLists.Add(new CertificationDetail {CertificationName = "REACH", Value = false});
        }
        else
        {
            certificationDetailLists.Add(new CertificationDetail { CertificationName = "RLIM", Value = false });
            certificationDetailLists.Add(new CertificationDetail { CertificationName = "RETIM", Value = true });
        }
        return Json(certificationDetailLists.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }

    public List<UploadInitialFile> GetAttachments()
    {
        return (List<UploadInitialFile>) Session["Upload"];
    }

    public ActionResult SaveAttachments(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                // Some browsers send file names with full path.
                // We are only interested in the file name.
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);
                var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

                SaveUploadedFileInSession(new UploadInitialFile(fileName, file.ContentLength, fileExtension));

                // The files are not actually saved in this demo
                file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
            }
        }

        // Return an empty string to signify success
        return Content("");
    }

    public ActionResult RemoveAttachments(string[] fileNames)
    {
        if (fileNames != null)
        {
            foreach (var fullName in fileNames)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fullName);
                var physicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), fileName);

                RemoveUploadedFileInSession(fileName);

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(physicalPath))
                {
                    // The files are not actually removed in this demo
                    System.IO.File.Delete(physicalPath);
                }
            }
        }

        // Return an empty string to signify success
        return Content("");
    }

    public void SaveUploadedFileInSession(UploadInitialFile uploadInitialFile)
    {
        List<UploadInitialFile> files;
        if (Session["Upload"] != null)
        {
            files = (List<UploadInitialFile>) Session["Upload"];
        }
        else
        {
            files = new List<UploadInitialFile>();
        }
        files.Add(uploadInitialFile);
        Session["Upload"] = files;
    }

    public void RemoveUploadedFileInSession(string fileName)
    {
        if (Session["Upload"] != null)
        {
            var files = (List<UploadInitialFile>)Session["Upload"];
            var updatedFiles = new List<UploadInitialFile>();

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file.Name != fileName)
                {
                    updatedFiles.Add(file);
                }
            }

            if (updatedFiles.Count > 0)
            {
                Session["Upload"] = updatedFiles;
            }
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveCertificationDetail([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, CertificationDetail model)
    {
        if (Session["Upload"] != null)
        {
            model.Attachments = (List<UploadInitialFile>) Session["Upload"];
        }

        return Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<input id="btnSearch" type="button" value="Search" class="btn btn-default icon-btn-input" />

<div class="col-sm-12">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoUIApp3.Models.Certification>()
          .Name("Grid1")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(e => e.SupplierNumber).Width("170px");
              columns.Bound(e => e.CustomerItemNumber).Width("170px");
          })
          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
          .Pageable(x => x.PageSizes(new object[] { 10, 20, 50, 100, "All" }))
          .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
          .AutoBind(false)
          .Selectable()
          .Sortable(sortable => sortable
              .AllowUnsort(true)
              .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
          .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(322))
          .Filterable(filterable => filterable
              .Extra(false)
              .Operators(operators => operators
                  .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                      .Contains("Contains")
                      .StartsWith("Starts with")
                      .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
                      .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to"))))
          .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .PageSize(10)
              .ServerOperation(false)
              .Read(read => read.Action("GetTestData", "Home"))
              .Model(model =>
              {
                  model.Id(p => p.SupplierNumber);
              }))
              .Events(events => events.Change("onRowSelect"))
    )
</div>
<br /><br />


<div class="col-sm-12">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoUIApp3.Models.CertificationDetail>()
          .Name("Grid2")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Command(command =>
              {
                  command.Edit().Text("Edit").HtmlAttributes(new { title = "Edit" });
              }).Width(180).Title("Action");
              columns.Bound(e => e.CertificationName).Width("170px");
              columns.Bound(e => e.Value).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' disabled #=Value == true ? checked='checked' : '' # />").Width("170px");
              columns.Bound(e => e.Attachments).Width("300px").ClientTemplate("#= getAttachments(Attachments)#").EditorTemplateName("_UploadAttachment");
          })
          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
          .Pageable(x => x.PageSizes(new object[] { 10, 20, 50, 100, "All" }))
          .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
          .AutoBind(false)
          .Selectable()
          .Sortable(sortable => sortable
              .AllowUnsort(true)
              .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
          .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(322))
          .Filterable(filterable => filterable
              .Extra(false)
              .Operators(operators => operators
                  .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                      .Contains("Contains")
                      .StartsWith("Starts with")
                      .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
                      .IsNotEqualTo("Is not equal to"))))
          .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
              .Ajax()
              .PageSize(10)
              .ServerOperation(false)
              .Read(read => read.Action("GetDetailTestData", "Home").Data("selectedRow"))
              .Model(model =>
              {
                  model.Id(p => p.CertificationName);
                  model.Field(p => p.CertificationName).Editable(false);
              })
              .Update(update => update.Action("SaveCertificationDetail", "Home")))
              .Events(e => e.Edit("onEdit"))
    )
</div>

<script>
    $('#btnSearch').click(function(e) {
        $('#Grid1').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
    });

    function selectedRow() {
        var grid = $("#Grid1").data("kendoGrid");
        var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
        var data = selectedItem ? selectedItem.toJSON() : {};

        return { model: data }
    }

    function onRowSelect() {
        $('#Grid2').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
    }

    function getAttachments(attachments) {
        var links = "";
        if (attachments!= null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
                links += "<a href=" + attachments[i].Name + " target='_blank' class='btn-success'>View Attachment</a><br/>";
            }
        }
        return links;
    }

    function onUploadSuccess(e) {
        if (e.response !== 'error') {
            var grid = $('#Grid2').data('kendoGrid');

            var item = grid.dataItem(this.element.closest("tr"));
            item.dirty = true;
        }
    }

    function onEdit(e) {
        $('.k-upload-empty').removeClass('k-upload-empty'); //need to do this to get border back in upload widget

        //add existing files in the upload widget
        if (e.model != null && e.model.Attachments != null) {
            var uniqueDataId = 1;
            var htmlCode ='';
            htmlCode += '<ul id="existing-files" class="k-upload-files k-reset">';

            for (var i = 0; i < e.model.Attachments.length; i++) {
                uniqueDataId++;
                var fileName = e.model.Attachments[i].Name;
                htmlCode +=
                    '<li class="k-file k-file-success" data-att-id="' +fileName + '">\
                    <span class="k-icon k-i-rtf">uploaded</span>\
                    <span class="k-filename" title="'+fileName +'">'+fileName +'</span>\
                    <strong class="k-upload-status">\
                    <span class="k-upload-pct"></span>\
                    </strong>\
                    <button type="button" class="k-button k-button-bare k-upload-action">\
                    <span class="k-icon k-i-close k-delete" title="Remove"></span>\
                    </button>\
                </li>';
            }
            htmlCode += '</ul>';

            var $files, item, _fn, _i, _len;
            if (htmlCode.length > 0) {
                $(".k-upload").append(htmlCode);
                $files = $(".k-file");
                _fn = function (item) {
                    var $item, fileId, filenames;
                    $item = $(item);
                    fileId = $item.data("att-id");
                    filenames = [
                      {
                          name: fileId
                      }
                    ];
                    return $item.data("fileNames", filenames);
                };
                for (_i = 0, _len = $files.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                    item = $files[_i];
                    _fn(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**_UploadAttachment.cshtml**

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .Name("files")
        .Async(a => a
            .Save("SaveAttachments", "Home")
            .Remove("RemoveAttachments", "Home")
            .AutoUpload(true)
        )
        .Events(e => e.Success("onUploadSuccess"))
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

That's why i doesn't get called.

You need to add a parameterless contructor for UploadInitialFile

it should be :

```
public class UploadInitialFile
    {
        public UploadInitialFile(){

        }

        public UploadInitialFile(string fileName, int contentLength, string fileExtension)
        {
            Name = fileName;
            Size = contentLength;
            Extension = fileExtension;
        }

        public string Name      { get; set; }
        public int Size         { get; set; }
        public string Extension { get; set; }
    }
```